# Reduce CPU usage while downloading files through HTTP

Tags: php, sockets

I've created a script that downloads very large files from the internet.

Something quite simple:

```
<?php
$source = fsockopen(…); // http
$destination = fopen(…,'wb'); // file
while (!feof($source))
{
  fwrite($destination,fread($source,4096));
}
fclose($source);
fclose($destination);
?>
```

It works great but this script uses 100% CPU on my server when downloading about 10 MB per second. Is it normal?

It is an Intel Xeon Quad Core X3323 @ 2.50 GHz.

P.S. It is in fact a little bit more complicated because my script reads HTTP headers first, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you shouldn't implement HTTP with sockets in the first place. Instead, use [curl](http://php.net/curl) or simply fopen wrappers, like

```
copy("http://example.net/", "example.html");
```

However, if you insist to do your own socket handling, note that `fread` will return an empty string if there is nothing to read. If your socket is in nonblocking mode, fread will immediately return `''`. You can call [`socket_set_block`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-block.php) to put the socket back in blocking mode:

```
<?php
$source = fsockopen(…); // http
$destination = fopen(…,'wb'); // file
socket_set_block($source);
stream_copy_to_stream($source, $destination);
fclose($source);
fclose($destination);
```

Comment: wouldn't the socket be blocking by default, unless the OP explicitly made it non-blocking?

Comment: @Alnitak Yup. However, the OP left out a lot of code, and there might  be a `socket_set_nonblock` in there. If the socket would be blocking, the loop would not cause 100% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

No, using 100% CPU just do that is not normal.

Have you considered using [`stream-copy-to-stream()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) to handle the copy from one file stream to the other?